# refactoring sample Python to-do list into web services, TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Tags: python, flask

Here is sample.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import urllib.request
import sqlite3
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def show_list():
    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:6000/api/items') as response:
        resp = response.read()
    resp = json.loads(resp)
    return render_template('index.html', todolist=resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=5000)
```

Here is sampleapi.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, g, request, url_for, jsonify
import sqlite3
import urllib.request

DATABASE = 'todolist.db'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route("/api/items")
def get_items():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('SELECT what_to_do, due_date, status FROM entries')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    tdlist = [dict(what_to_do=row[0], due_date=row[1], status=row[2])
              for row in entries]
    return jsonify(tdlist)

def get_db():
    """open new db connection.
    """
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    """Close db at the end of the request."""
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", port=6000)
```

This is the error I get:

```
File "sample.py", line 14, in show_list
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

So I believe I have to change `urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:6000/api/items') as response:`

as we can't use urllib library to send POST requests, as it sends the data in bytes instead of JSON. So how do I use the requests library, which can send data over http protocol as json?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can definitely be solved without `requests`, but it's much easier to use than `urllib` anyway so I recommend it. Here is what you would do:

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://localhost:6000/api/items').json()
```

Comment: Thanks @alex-hall. Any idea how I can enhance the form to create or delete an entry?

Comment: @RobbieTheK that's a very broad question with many parts, you'll need to narrow it down.